# How to C# Core OAuth without external login panel

Tags: c#, api, oauth, asp.net-core, exact-online

I'm making an API for Exact Online for a website with a form. The visitor will fill in his information and after that the visitor sends it. It need to be send to the Exact online account from my client. But before that I need a accesstoken. The problem is that I don't want to give the user the login page that Exact gives me. I'm searching already for days to find a way to skip the login or to enter the login information by backend (there is always 1 login, and that is the login from my client).

Now this authorization thing is something new for me. So far I know I can call my authorization settings from the startup with this:

HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync("ExactOnline");

But then I get that loginscreen that I don't want. The only thing that Exact is telling me to do:

Create an app registration that supports an automated connection wizard (your provisioning process).

Is there a way to send them the login information and the visitor doesn't see a loginpage.

In my Startup.cs

```
var s = new OAuthOptions{
AuthenticationScheme = "ExactOnline",
ClientId = "CLIENTID",
ClientSecret = "CLIENTSECRET",
CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback"),
AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
AutomaticChallenge = true,
AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/api/oauth2/auth", "https://start.exactonline.nl")).ToString(),
TokenEndpoint = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/api/oauth2/token", "https://start.exactonline.nl")).ToString(),
//Scope = { "identity", "roles" },
Events = new OAuthEvents
{
    OnCreatingTicket = context =>
    {
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:token:exactonline", context.AccessToken));
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
}; 
app.UseOAuthAuthentication(s);
```

First i had this code, but that  gives me a null exception when i put the identity in the claimprincipal, probably because my claimsprincipal is null and i don't know why.

```
HttpContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("ExactOnline");

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("ExactOnline",ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
identity.Label = "Authentication";
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "USERNAME?"));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "PASSWORD?"));

claimsPrincipal.AddIdentity(identity);

var test = HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("ExactOnline", claimsPrincipal, new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }));
```

After that i tried following code, but that also didn't work. My code will continue, but the test variable will be filled with this message: The name 'InnerExceptionCount' does not exist in the current context.

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("ExactOnline", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
identity.Label = "Authentication";
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "USERNAME"));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("password", "PASSWORD"));
ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

var test = HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("ExactOnline", claimsPrincipal, new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false });
```

Someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't. Part of the authentication flow is that you don't have access to the username and password of the user logging on.

Comment: @PatrickHofman and what if i have a webshop and want that the application add everything to Exact Accounting system? i can't tell the visitor or my client to login everytime. I have access to the username and password of my client. So i want to know if it's possible and how to fix this.

Comment: Then you have to ask the administrator to authenticate once using an admin panel and use the token and refresh token. If I may suggest, you can also save all relevant data to your database and synchronize the relevant information to Exact Online using an ETL tool that supports Exact Online, for example Invantive Data Hub (from the company I work for).

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't have a problem to use the refreshtoken, but i asked Exact and they told me that if i use the refresh token, that i have to login **Not very often** and they told that i need to make a mechanism for if they expire all the tokens in there system. The form in the website needs to work 24/7 and if backend login isn't possible as fallback repair, then i can't let it work 24/7 if there will be one time they expire all the tokens. Btw with ETL tool you mean this?
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.ExactOnlineODBCDriver

Comment: First of all you shouldn't rely on a 100% uptime for Exact Online. They have had some serious outages and other related problems. You should always have a plan B (your database as primary source to supply information to Exact). And no, I mean this product: http://www.invantive.com/products/invantive-data-hub.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thank you, I will look at the program next week!

Comment: Hi Devo, I am facing the same issue now. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: 1 year and 6 month later and I am having a similar problem now. :)
I aim to export invoice data from one of my company's apps to Exact Online for one of our customers. They'd like it to be as painless as possible, so automation would be best, without having to log in everytime for the export.
Still struggling with how to overcome OAuth2 so I can simply speak to the REST API.

Comment: I have initialized an authentication in my startup file (I am using C#, so not sure how it works with other languages) with callback and authorization url etc. After that I created a authorization path for the administrator. If the admin goes to that url he will be forwarded to the authorization url of Exact. After he logs in he will be redirected to the redirect url. Exact Online will send a access token and refresh token to your callback url. Store those somewhere (I use a database table). With the refresh token you can refresh your access token programmatically.

Comment: I use this method for my Mollie authentication and it is working without any problems for more then a year now.